# Port Forwarding with UPnP

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, indy10

I am developing a p2p chat application in delphi indy 10 . I have two questions.

1.I am using this function for port opening . It gives Coinitialize has not been called error .i declared that but don't know whether i declared it in right place because if i run it in Xp it still gives this error.

2.If i am using udp hole punching then why i need to call this function? i m not able to chat if i do-not call this function.

```
  procedure AddPortThroughUPnP;

  var
  NAT     : Variant;
  Profile : Variant;
  Ports   : Variant;

begin

  if ( not fEnableUPnP ) or ( fServerRole ) then exit;

  if fWindowsName = WINXP then
  begin
  try
  Coinitialize(nil);
    NAT      := CreateOleObject ( 'HNetCfg.FwMgr' );
    Profile  := NAT.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile;

    if not VarIsClear ( Profile ) then
    begin

      Ports          := CreateOLEObject('HNetCfg.FWOpenPort');
      Ports.Name     := 'UDP Server 6002';
      Ports.Port     := 6002;
      Ports.Scope    := 0;
      Ports.Protocol := 17;
      Ports.Enabled  := True;

      Profile.GloballyOpenPorts.Add ( Ports );

    end;
  finally
     Couninitialize;
  end;

  end
  else
  begin
         try
   Coinitialize(nil);
    NAT   := CreateOleObject ( 'HNetCfg.NATUPnP' );
    Ports := NAT.StaticPortMappingCollection;

    if not VarIsClear ( Ports ) then
       Ports.Add
       ( 6002, 'UDP', fExternalPort, fLocalIP, True, 'UDP Server 6002' );

         finally
         Couninitialize;
         end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You have to call `CoInitializeEx()` before you try to open `HNetCfg.FwMgr` object. But you're calling it only for `HNetCfg.NATUPnP`. Also, your function will fail if you run it on `Windows XP` that has firewall service stopped/disabled.

Comment: Now i have called coinitialize and Couninitialize for both if and else but unfortunately no message is sent between clients.if i remove it they get messages.

Comment: i have edited my post by the updated code.And i also enabled xp firewall.

Comment: "I am using this function." What function?

Comment: I cannot say why the code fails, but you need to clear your Variant values before calling `CoUninitialize()` so the COM objects are released before COM itself is uninitialized, otherwise you can cause crashes in your code. With that said, you should not be calling `CoInitialize/CoUninitialize()` on a per-function basis to begin with, since a thread's COM model can only be set once. You should call `CoInitialize()` when the calling thread starts running, and `CoUninitialize()` just before the calling thread stops running.

Comment: DID ANYONE MADE THAT WORK?